# UITextView hasText not working?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am assigning the contents of the clipboard to the UITextView text property.  However, when I check the hasText property, the condition is always false.

```
NSString paste_text = [[NSString alloc] init];
self.paste_text = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string; 

....

my_UITextView.text = self.paste_text;


//THIS CONDITION IS ALWAYS FALSE

if (my_UITextView hasText)
    { UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:
            @"Text ready to copy"
            message:err_msg
            delegate:nil
            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
            otherButtonTitles:nil];

      [alert show];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your paste_text isn't used as intended since right after you alloc, it will immediately be discarded, possibly released, maybe not.  You could actually just do away with the `[[NSString alloc] init];`.

Then add the following to test your code:

```
// delete:
//     NSString paste_text = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSLog([UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string);
    self.paste_text = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string; 

NSLog(self.paste_text);
    ....

    my_UITextView.text = self.paste_text;

NSLog(@"my_UITextView is %@, text contained: %@, my_UITextView , my_UITextView.text);
```

The first `NSLog` prints out the pasteboard string, the second the string once it is passed on to your `paste_text`, and the last will let you know if `my_UITextView` is non-nil, and what text it contains.

Also, if paste_text is a @property, what are its attributes?  The text from `[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string` needs to be copied into it, otherwise when the pasteboard's string is changed, so is your `paste_text`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to send your UITextView the hasText message by using brackets:

```
if ([my_UITextView hasText])
```

**UPDATE:**

Do you know that your UTTextView has text? You might want to check it on the console:

```
my_UITextView.text = self.paste_text;

NSLog(@"my_UITextView.text = %@",my_UITextView.text); // check for text

//THIS CONDITION IS ALWAYS FALSE

if ([my_UITextView hasText])
```

Comment: "That does not seem to be working either".  This could mean:


1. my_UITextView causes an exception
2. that code makes your app barf
3. my_UITextView.text contains garbage
4. my_UITextView.text is nil
5. my_UITextView.text is a zero length string
6. I can go on...

In order for us to help you, you need to do a little bit more work and let us know what "not working" is.  Do a little debugging, provide us with the results, and then we're better armed to help you.  See below on what debugging you could do.

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the my_UITextView property? If you did it in InterfaceBuilder, it's possible that you forgot to create an IBOutlet.